# XSD - restrict/redefine complexType with occurs 0

Tags: xml, schema

I have a complexType User:

```
<xs:complexType name="User">
    <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="id" type="xs:positiveInteger" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="email" type="email" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="password" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
```

and I have to use it with constraints on elements minOccurs and maxOccurs.

For example by login I need the User with email and password elements only, so I need any other elements (id,name) with maxOccurs=0 and minOccurs=0.

```
<Auth:login>
    <User>
        <email>my@email.net</email>
        <password>mypass</password>
    </User>
</Auth:login>
```

Is it possible to validate the XML above with a restricted complexType of User?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: type R can only restrict type B if all instances of R are valid instances of B. Since B requires id and name to be present, a type that requires them (or even permits them) to be absent is not a valid restriction of B.

Comment: Okay, I understand, and is there a simple way to solve this problem, or should I write every field (element) of a restricted class (complexType) manually? (I don't need redundancy :S, it's always a source of bugs.)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with assertions (in xsd 1.1), but I think php has only xsd 1.0 support :S

I found [here](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/84926-occurence-constraints-xsd) some help. I can put my sub elements into groups, and concatenate the actually needed groups.